# PHP beautify URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I got this basic url and I want to rewrite it with my .htaccess file:

`https://server.com/paste.php?pasteid=cNdwKj4D4vPWDhm`

I already tried to rewrite the URL but this did not work quite well.

I want to end up with this:

```
https://server.com/paste/cNdwKj4D4vPWDhm
```

The GET parameter is dynamic so it is not always the same.

I hope this is really possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^paste/(.*)?$ paste.php?pasteid=$1`